# aws incoming data from cloudwatch logs group to lambda is broken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

my Design is like this,

Cloudtrail -> trail -> cloudwatch logs & S3 -> lambda -> slack

```
                                        ***
```

logs are fine including eventVersion and Name and stuffs
But, that part cloudwatch logs -> lambda is the problem. when i print out the 'event' data (the original data first arrived lambda) to debug and it goes like this
{ awslogs: 
{ data: 'H4sIA~~~~~~~ all the random letters. not like eventVersion and such.

I think there's problem with encoding. I've tried to sent it as JSON and cloudtrail type. I of course screen only events I want to get from the logs in lambda like (if event=='updategroup')&& so on. 
there is no filter pattern bc i wanted to catch all event first,
lambda written with js.

Please help, or suggest better design.

Answer (score 3):

The following Python3 code is an example of decoding cloudwatch events in a lambda function:

```
import json
import base64
import gzip
from io import BytesIO

cw_data = str(event['awslogs']['data'])
cw_logs = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(base64.b64decode(cw_data, validate=True))).read()
log_events = json.loads(cw_logs)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Using CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filters - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html):

> The Data attribute in the Lambda record is Base64 encoded and compressed with the gzip format. The actual payload that Lambda receives is in the following format `{ "awslogs": {"data": "BASE64ENCODED_GZIP_COMPRESSED_DATA"} }` You can examine the raw data from the command line using the following Unix commands:
>
> ```
> echo -n "<BASE64ENCODED_GZIP_COMPRESSED_DATA>" | base64 -d | zcat
> ```

So, your Lambda function will need to unzip and then decode base64.

Answer (score 0):

C# version of Cloudwatch log to Lambda:

```
public class clsAws
{
    public clsAwsLogs awsLogs;
}
public class clsAwsLogs
{
    public string data;

}
public class Function
{
    public static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

        int cnt;

        while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
        }
    }

    public static string Unzip(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (MemoryStream msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        using (MemoryStream mso = new MemoryStream())
        {
           using (GZipStream gz = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                CopyTo(gz, mso);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
        }
    }
    public void FunctionHandler(JsonElement input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        string json = input.GetRawText();
        clsAws clsAws = new clsAws();
        clsAws = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clsAws>(json);
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(clsAws.awsLogs.data);
        string base64Decoded = Unzip(data);
    }
}
```